# How to add header / footer on export on django import-export?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using the django-import-export plugin in admin, and i would like to add a header/footer(images) when exporting data.

Is there a way to get a handle on the excel or pdf object maybe when overriding `export` or `before_export` ?

Comment: You can use 'after_export' : https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.after_export

Comment: after_export doesn't give me a handle for the document to manipulate it

Comment: It does recieve `data` object which is a `Tablib.Dataset`  instance, which you can manipulate.

https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L704

Comment: ah ok, but can the data contain images ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**django-import-export**](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/) modules' core functionalities depend on the other package named [**tablib**](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/). You can't achieve what you are intended to do merely by overriding few methods which belong to **django-import-export** package since the [**`export().format_name`**](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#exporting-data) **`property`** belongs to **tablib** package.

---

### Workaround (the hard one)

1. Create a new format or edit the existing. ref [**Adding New Formats** (tablib doc)](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/#adding-new-formats)
2. After editing the source code, build your own `tablib` python package
3. build your own `django-import-export` by wiring-up the *custom `tablib` package*
4. wire-up the *custom `django-import-export`* package in your django project

Comment: ouf! this is the only solution ? no way without rewriting the packages ? Is there any other library that's better suited for export ?

Comment: As I said, the core functionalities are from ***`lablib`*** package. AFAIK, I don't think there is an existing out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: I'm not a user of these packages (import/export), I went through the source code and I found these things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding `get_export_data()` in a custom Admin class.  The super class `get_export_data()` will return the xlsx data.  This can be loaded into a Openpyxl workbook and then modified.  This only works with 'xlsx' files.

(example taken from django-import-export example app)

```py
from io import BytesIO

from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile
from openpyxl import load_workbook

class BookAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'author', 'added')
    list_filter = ['categories', 'author']
    resource_class = BookResource

    def get_export_data(self, file_format, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns file_format representation for given queryset.
        """
        export_data = super().get_export_data(file_format, queryset, *args, **kwargs)
        wb = load_workbook(BytesIO(export_data))
        ws = wb.active
        ws.insert_rows(1)
        ws["A1"] = "NEW ROW"

        with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
            wb.save(f.name)
            data = BytesIO(f.read())

        return data
```